# Cover Half Width of Parent in ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

I have a ViewGroup (lets call this **A**) in which a child is added. I want the **A** to be half the width of the parent.

Now in onMeasure I am setting the width to half of the parent size which comes in widthMeasureSpec but the problem I am facing is that the A view covers the half of the screen but the measurement does not due to which the children are not placed correctly.

Below is my onMeasure and onLayout.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int widthLimit = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingRight();
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    int rightPadding = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        rightPadding = child.getPaddingRight();
        measureChild(child, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((widthLimit / 2) - rightPadding - child.getPaddingLeft(), widthMode), heightMeasureSpec);

        width += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        height += child.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    width = widthLimit / 2;
    width -= rightPadding;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, resolveSize(height, heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

I have added an example view for reference with the issue.

[image]

Comment: whay are you calling `width += child.getMeasuredWidth();` in a loop and when loop is done you call `width = widthLimit / 2;` it makes no sense at all

Comment: yes you are correct. it was for debugging purposes.